# how to get next relative dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

i have this code

```
<div id="aggregate" style="display:inline">
                    <%=Html.RadioButton("a", "1", true, new {id = "meRadio"})%><label>Me</label>
                    <%=Html.RadioButton("a", "2", false, new { id = "teamRadio" })%><label>Team: </label><% = Html.DropDownList("Teams", Model.Teams,  new {@scope="Team",  @id = "teamDropdown", @class = "filterDropdown" })%>
                    <%=Html.RadioButton("a", "4", false, new { id = "managerRadio" })%><label>Manager: </label><% = Html.DropDownList("Managers", Model.People, new { @scope = "Manager", @id = "managerDropdown", @class = "filterDropdown" })%>
                    <%=Html.RadioButton("a", "5", false, new { id = "locationRadio" })%><label>Location: </label><% = Html.DropDownList("Locations", Model.Locations, new { @scope = "Location", @id = "locationDropdown", @class = "filterDropdown" })%>
  </div>
```

i currently have code like this:

```
 $('#workstreamRadio').click(function () {
     Enable("#workstreamDropdown");
 });

 $('#teamRadio').click(function () {
     Enable("#teamDropdown");
 });
```

I am sure there is a way using jquery to dynamically get the respective dropdown selector given a specific radio button clicked so i dont have to hard code each mapping.

what is the syntax for saying  "get me the selector of the dropdown to the right of the radio button i clicked"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) like this:

```
$("#aggregate :radio").change(function() {
  var dropdown = $(this).nextAll("select:first");
  //enable or disable dropdown
});
```

since they're siblings, use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) which goes through all siblings, and you want the first `<select>` element, so select that from the siblings after the radio clicked.  Also look at using [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) here instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), it'll fire only when the selection changes, which is *usually* what you want here.

Comment: will this handle the first entry which has no dropdown.  i only want this to apply to all other radio buttons except the first one as the first one has slightly different logic. i was thinking of having a class attribute on all radio buttons except the first one to solve this.

Comment: @ooo - You can change the selector for binding, change `$("#aggregate :radio")` to `$("#aggregate :radio:gt(0)")` to ignore the first radio, and it won't be bound :)

Comment: why `nextAll('select:first')` and not `next('select')`?

Comment: @Alexander - `.next()` finds *only* the *very* next element *if* it matches the selector...it doesn't continue to look until it finds one, it's a bit counter-intuitive.